# Razor is removing curly brace on second if statement

Tags: c#, razor

I am getting a really strange error when i try to run my C# app locally. I am new to web development in c# so i may be missing something simple. I have searched for a while and found some very similar questions, but I could not find anyone with this error for the same reason.

At the top of my cshtml file that is causing the error i have this code:

My Code:

```
@{
    var addr = ViewBag.Address;
    if (addr == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Address is null");
    }
    string addrString = @addr.Street + " " + @addr.City + ", " + @addr.State + " " + @addr.Postal + " " + @addr.Country;
    addrString = addrString.Trim();
    int lastSpot = addrString.Length - 1;
    if (addrString[lastSpot] == ',')
    {
        addrString = addrString.Remove(lastSpot);
    }
}
```

When i run it i get this error. If i remove the second if statement the error goes away
Error:

Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Source Error:

```
Line 619:        }
Line 620:    }
Line 621:}
```

When I look in the file generated by Razor i see this: Notice the second closing brace has been taken out:

```
Line 55:    if (addrString[lastSpot] == ',')
Line 56:       {
Line 57:           addrString = addrString.Remove(lastSpot);
Line 58:       
Line 59:               
Line 60:               #line default
Line 61:               #line hidden
Line 62:   BeginContext("~/Views/Home/ResolveAddress.cshtml", 438, 268, true);
```

I have no clue why the second brace is not being recognized and any suggestions would be great.
Also, my cshtml file is only 208 lines long.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

```
string addrString = @addr.Street + " " + @addr.City + ", " + @addr.State + " " + @addr.Postal + " " + @addr.Country;
```

the @ signs are not necessary as you do not want to switch between C# and markup. And they most likely cause the problem.

So the fix is:

```
string addrString = addr.Street + " " + addr.City + ", " + addr.State + " " + addr.Postal + " " + addr.Country;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all the "@" characters on the line the starts with "string addrString". Change it to this and it gets the braces back in sync:

```
string addrString = addr.Street + " " + addr.City + ", " + addr.State + " " + addr.Postal + " " + addr.Country;
```

As an aside with that many concatenations you may want to use string.Format().